# Current Fragment on SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

im using new away to use tabs with viewPager, but i dont know how to know what is the current fragment showing.

At the moment im getting an issue, that is loggint two items on method getItems, from pagerAdapater. I mean, when fragment loads, i see two getItems logs.

So, i dont know what is the fragament shwoing at the moment, and pass that information for my class fragment.

I have two classes 
[SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) and [SlidingTabStrip](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html), in my project.

And my classes...

Note: I didnt post my Fragment class, because is a simple class and doesnt matter for debug, because issue is happening before.

**MyActivity**

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(myactivity.xml);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) this
            .findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
 }
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

private static int TABS = 6;

public MyPagerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

/**
 * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position. 
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.d("Just for log:" + position);
    return new MyFragment();
}

/**
 * Return the number of views available. 
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return TABS;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch(position){

        case 0: return "TAB 1"; 
        case 1: return "TAB 2";
        case 2: return "TAB 3";
        case 3: return "TAB 4";
        case 4: return "TAB 5";
        case 5: return "TAB 6";
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

**myactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_activity"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<my.package.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</my.package.common.view.SlidingTabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every class that extends Fragment can override the following method:

    `@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`
so, this gives you (or the fragment) the information that it is now
becoming visible (or unvisible). You can then pass this information
to holder Activity class.